# angularjs 1.5 : How to identify what is getting leaked and fix the leak?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

Tested in chrome latest and other browsers. This page starts a `timer()` to refresh every 60 seconds. On `init()` and every `refresh()`, it gets data from the server and display the same in the page. We see that it leaks lot of MB every refresh.

1. Now, how do I identify the specific objects and/or DOM Nodes that are being leaked
2. Once I identify the object/Nodes from #1, how do I go about fixing the leaks ?

Are there any books, good tutorials that would cover the above for Angularjs 1.5 ?

Comment: A good start would be trying out the Profiler in you Developer tools (or Memory in newer Chrome versions).

Comment: I needed more details to get it to work. I googled for "How to find memory leaks using Chrome dev tools" and was able to identify detached DOM objects. But from there, I could not get to anything concrete.

Answer (score 1):

You probably found https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/ and http://www.dwmkerr.com/fixing-memory-leaks-in-angularjs-applications/ as there are no more detailed resource out there.

> > A DOM node can only be garbage collected when there are no references to it from either the page's DOM tree or JavaScript code. A node is said to be "detached" when it's removed from the DOM tree but some JavaScript still references it. Detached DOM nodes are a common cause of memory leaks.

1. If you're not holding a reference of the timer but creating a new timer on every refresh - leak, solvable by reusing the `$timeout`
2. Checkout - CTRL + F `$scope is retained by a context for a closure.` on second provided link. The use case explained there is so similar to one you're having. Further on in the article:

> > We can open the function and examine it for issues. There's an $http.get which has as closure which uses $scope, but alarmingly there is an $interval registered to run every 10 seconds, which is never deregistered. The interval callback uses another $http.get, with a closure that uses $scope. This is the problem.

If none of the above applies then here's the list of open issues in `AngularJS` having `memory leak` as a keyword:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen%20memory%20leak

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will help you are not(maybe you've already looked into it), but it is worth mentioning. I had a similar issue with a previous application where objects were continuously being duplicated during every ajax request. So from the load of the page i would be using about 50mb of memory, but after making 10-15 ajax calls the memory would sky rocket to >1gb.

I was able to identify and resolve the issue using chrome dev tools -> memory tab. Through here you are able to record allocation profiles of memory and get a heap snapshot. So, for your situation i might cut the timer down to 5 or 10 seconds for testing purposes, then run these profilers. You will be able to get a view of what methods are being called and at what cost.

Hope this helps.